# Equivalent HMAC SHA-512 key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, hmac, digest

what is the equivalent HMAC SHA-512 key for the following one? **01c17afc4be444d9f27ff3b11cd206f79cbcd0fa7e262d90587338f7d5a70f92**

What is the code use to get for this in ruby? I found no online converters to check this with HMAC.

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent"? The string you presented looks like a HEX encoding of 32 bytes which can be used as a key for HMAC SHA-512.

Answer (score 4):

You can use following code to create signature using HMAC and sha512 in ruby,

```
digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha512')
signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, private_key, data)
```

The "data" is the actual data that you want to sign. if you just want to create instance then you can use `instance = OpenSSL::HMAC.new(private_key, digest)` and then update method.

For more information on HMAC using ruby with sample code -

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/HMAC.html

Comment: What is data? I want to pass only private_key

Comment: The "data" is data that you you want to sign. if you just want to create instance then you can use `instance = OpenSSL::HMAC.new(private_key, digest)`

Comment: Kindly read my question. My requirement is just find the equivalent HMAC sha512 value for the above key. i.e 01c17afc4be444d9f27ff3b11cd206f79cbcd0fa7e262d90587338f7d5a70f92

Comment: `hexdigest` probably should be used instead of `digest`